# Identify lines of speech which contain words from a list using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, keyword

I have the following dataframe:

```
test = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Line No.','Person','Speech'])
test['Person'] = ['A','B','A','B','A','B']
test['Line No.'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
test['Speech'] = ['hello. how was your assessment day? i heard it went very well.',
                  'The beginning was great and the rest of the day was kinda ok.',
                   'why did things go from great to ok?',
                 'i was positive at the beginning and went right with all my answers but then i was not feeling well.',
                 "that's very unfortunate. if there's anything i can help you with please let me know how.",
                 'Will do.']
```

And the following list which contains keywords:

```
keywords = ['hello','day','great','well','happy','right','ok','why','positive']
```

I would like to generate an output which shows both the speaker and line no. associated with them for each time their speech contains at least 3 words from the keywords list. I have tried iterating through each line in the dataframe to see if there was at least 3 keywords present however my code only returns the last line. Below is the code I used:

```
def identify_line_numebr(dataframe, keywords:list, thresh:int=3):
    is_person = False
    keyword_match_list = []

for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
    if is_person == False:
        # Pulling out the speech
        line = row['Speech']
        for token in line:
            # Checking if each line of speech contains key words
            if token in keywords:
                keyword_match_list.append(token)
                print(index, is_person, row['Line No.'], row['Person'])
                print(len(keyword_match_list))
            
            if len(keyword_match_list) == thresh:
                is_person == True
    else:
        break
        
return {row['Person'], row['Line No.']}
```

The expected output for this particular case should be in a similar format:

```
output = [{1, 'A'},{2, 'B'},{3, 'A'},{5, 'A'}]
```

whereby the first value is the Line No. which contains speech which has at least 3 keywords and the letter is the person.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you stop the iteration over the rows as soon as you find a line containing at least three keywords. Instead, you should iterate over all lines and add the person and line number to a list if the threshold count is met:

```
def identify_line_numbers(dataframe, keywords, thresh=3):

    person_line = []  # will contain sets of {Line No., Person}
    for line_index, line in enumerate(dataframe.Speech):

        # check if each word is in the current line
        words_in_speech = [word in line for word in keywords]
    
        # add person and line number to our list if the threshold count is met
        if sum(words_in_speech) >= thresh:

            person_line.append(
                {dataframe.Person[line_index], dataframe['Line No.'][line_index]}
            )

    return person_line
```